# Julia: how do I configure IJulia kernel to use specific environment?

Tags: julia, virtual-environment, ijulia-notebook

I downloaded someone else's project and the structure is as follows:

```
project/
    notebooks/
        notebook_a.ipynb
        notebook_b.ipynb
    library/
        Manifest.toml
        Project.toml
        src/
        test/
```

In the notebooks I would like to import `library`, and install its dependencies within its own evironment.

Following the sugestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406075/how-to-set-julia-environment-for-ijulia-jupyter-notebook), I can do

```
using Pkg
Pkg.activate("../library/")
```

but I wonder if I could install a kernel that has the project directory specified and automatically activates the `library` environment. What should I pass to `IJulia`'s `installkernel`? `"--project=..."` what?

I use `conda` regularly and this confused me because I thought that running `notebook` once the environment is activated in the command line would have the right environment in the notebook, but this was not the case.

Answer (score 2):

IJulia starts its own Julia process and hence is not using environment settings from its master.

By default IJulia sets the environment (`Project.toml`) from the folder it was started. The most convenient thing would be to move the `notebooks` folder to be subfolder of `library` and then just run:

```
notebook(dir="/path/to/project/library")
```

If you do not want to change the folder structure you still need to run:

```
notebook(dir="/path/to/project/notebooks")
```

Once in the notebook you need to run:

```
using Pkg
pkg"activate /path/to/project/library"
```

Comment: It is enough that Project.toml and Manifest.toml are found in the parent of the directory of the folder of the notebook (to be precise a `--project=@.` option is used).